# Spring Security gives Null authentification when retriving username in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to get user's name like this:

```
public static String getUsername() {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return userDetails.getUsername();
}
```

It works fine when just loggined, but when go to a different page context becomes `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication` with `authentification = null`. 
How do I retrieve logged in user with Spring Security in Spring Boot correctly? 
Spring Boot version is 2.0.3.RELEASE.

UPD:
To clarify: After navigating to another page `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` gives a context with `authentification = null`. So `context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` throws `NullPointerException` because `context.getAuthentication()` is null.

Comment: Could you please add related code where you're getting the null?

Comment: @MadhuBhat updated the answer to clarify what gives NullPointerException. The is just SecurityUtils.getUsername(). I want to show a user his/her name.

Comment: What I meant was, could you please elaborate on what "navigating to another page" means code-wise? Are you using spring mvc or anything else? Are you accessing any unauthenticated api while navigating to another page? Would need more to understand where you're getting the null Auth. Would be better to add more details with specific code where you're getting the null Auth.

Comment: @MadhuBhat I use Vaadin to create frontend. I use Route annotation to define my pages and their paths. By "navigating to another page" I mean any page except login page. After I logged in and my main page is loaded - NullPoiterException there is. I can show login page code, but it's Vaadin specific.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is wrong, but I found a workaround - I save username in session.
Since I use Vaadin - I use VaadinSession, but I believe HttpSession can be used as well.

```
public static String getUsername() {
  VaadinSession session = VaadinSession.getCurrent();
  if(session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    session.setAttribute("username", userDetails.getUsername());
  }
  return (String) session.getAttribute("username");
}
```

The only thing - this code works only in Components, so you must make sure to use it from autowired classes.